# isc-dhcp-server can't get DHCPDISCOVER packet from some clients whose MAC address not in the subnet

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

`isc-dhcp-server` running normal, it can offer IP address to most clients in all `subnet` which are defined in the **dhcpd.conf** file, but it can't receive some `DHCPDISCOVER` packet from several clients which also in the same define `subnet` without the static MAC address config.

Some segment of **dhcpd.conf**:

```
subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 10.10.10.1;
        next-server 10.10.10.100;
        filename "pxelinux.0";
        host 10-10-10-72 {hardware ethernet     BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BF;fixed-address 10.10.10.72;}
        host 10-10-10-73 {hardware ethernet     BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:B0;fixed-address 10.10.10.73;}}
```

FYI. All `subnet` config are static define, the clients which can't send `DHCPDISCOVER` to `isc-dhcp-server` owns MAC address are not included the **dhcpd.conf**.

`/var/log/message` the default dhcp server's log can't get the `DHCPDISCOVER` request log.

After add the new MAC address's config to **dhcpd.conf**, then restart `isc-dhcp-server`, it works for all clients.

What is the base principle of `isc-dhcp-server`?

Maybe there are not define the MAC address configure of the request client in the **dhcpd.conf** file?

Or there are not exist the dynamic address range in the `subnet` config?

Comment: So you are saying that DHCP works as expected after you fixed the syntax errors in dhcpd.conf. And you seem to be surprised. I would be surprised of the opposite: If it worked with syntax errors.

Comment: @berndbausch update the question, plz check.

Comment: You mean you define a subnet without explicitly stating MAC addresses. Some clients don't get a DHCP response, and you see no trace of DHCPDISCOVERY in /var/log/messages. Once you add those MAC addresses explicitly, as shown in the snippet you provide, the clients do get a DHCP response, and you see expected messages in the log file. Did I understand that right? I don't think anybody can help you without seeing your dhcpd.conf.

Comment: @berndbausch yes, you understand me. I could get the bootps request by `tcpdump port 67 or port 68 | grep 'the MAC address'` always, but not in `/var/log/messages` before add those MAC address explicitly in **dhcpd.conf**.